# How to insert inline `code` in Lyx

Tags: lyx, code

I want to add an inline text formatted as `code` in Lyx. For example:

"The gradient is calculated via `math::gradient(v)`"

I am aware of the Insert List command, but it is not what I'm looking for since the code listing is not inserted inline. I have searched everywhere, but I can't find the way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most common options are `\verb` from the LaTeX base classes, `\lstinline` from the `listings` package, or `\mintinline` from the `minted` package. I suggest using the `listings` package because it provides some basic highlighting customization but doesn't require an external program to be run during compilation.

Comment: Thanks @siracusa!. Actually Lyx is using the \begin{lstlisting} when using the Insert Listing option, but the listing is not inserted inline...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert an inline program listing in LyX as follows:

1. Insert > Program Listing
2. With the cursor inside the newly created listings box, go to Edit > Listings Settings (or right click inside the box and choose "Settings").
3. In the settings dialog, check the box "Inline listing".

Starting with [LyX 2.3.0](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX23), you can optionally choose to (globally) use the minted package for listings, by going to Document > Settings > Listings and selecting "Minted" in the combo box.

Comment: Can you create a shortcut for inline listing? I managed to create a shortcut for `listing-insert`, but that only create a program listing, and does not set it as inline listing...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do that.